# Powershell object as parameter

Tags: object, powershell, exchange-server

i got some problem while preparing some useful script based on PS.

I try to make script which will collect data from Active Directory and Exchange (users/mailboxes), then this data will be processed in further part of script (in some function for example)

```
function toProcess($userObj, $mailboxObj)
{
  echo $userObj.enabled #the output is null
}

$users = get-adusers -Filter * -properties *
foreach($user in $users)
{
  $guid = $user.objectGuid.toString()
  if($user.mail -ne $null)
  {
    $mailbox = get-mailbox $guid | select-object *
    if($mailbox -ne $null)
    {
       toProcess($user, $mailbox)
    }       
  }
}
```

When there is assigned only one parameter ($user) to the onProcess(), function executes correctly and display status of account. When i assign two objects, values becomes null.
What's wrong?

I use powershell 2.0

Answer (score 3):

When calling PowerShell functions, arguments are separated by spaces, and parentheses are not needed.

Your function call should look like this.

```
toProcess $user $mailbox
```

By placing a comma between the variables, you were creating a single argument that is an array of objects.